# I want to change straight line to curve line on my OD analysis

Tags: qgis, symbology, line, curve

I have an OD analysis of Bicycle stations. But straight lines are overlapping. So I need to convert radial or curved line to solve this problem. How can I do?

Current:

[image]

Desired:

[image]

Comment: @Nikos I don't think that post is relevant.

Comment: Oh apologies. I will delete it.